# Namespace not matching in WLS Published WSDL for JAX-WS RPC Style webservice

Tags: weblogic, jax-ws, jax-rpc

After deploying a JAX-WS, RPC Style webservice, the WSDL published in 
Weblogic server 12.1.3 does not corresponds to initial WSDL. The namespace in 
 is not matching.

### ISSUE:

Initial WSDL Contains:

```
<soap12:body parts="helloReq" use="literal" namespace=""/>
```

Published WSDL Contains:

```
<soap12:body use="literal" namespace="http://sample"/>
```

Due to this, inappropriate SOAP Request is getting formed which is throwing 
error on invocation : "Cannot find dispatch method for {}hello".

Initial WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://sample">

        <xsd:complexType name="hello">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="input" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexType name="helloResponse">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="output" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:schema>

</types>

<message name="hello">
    <part name="helloReq" type="tns:hello" />
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
    <part name="helloRes" type="tns:helloResponse" />
</message>

<portType name="HelloServicePort">
    <operation name="hello">
        <input message="tns:hello" />
        <output message="tns:helloResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding type="tns:HelloServicePort" name="HelloServicePort">
    <soap12:binding style="rpc"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="hello">
        <soap12:operation style="rpc" soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap12:body parts="helloReq" use="literal" namespace="" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap12:body parts="helloRes" use="literal" namespace="" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="HelloService">
    <port name="HelloServicePort" binding="tns:HelloServicePort">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:7201/hello/HelloService" />
    </port>
</service>
```

Published WSDL:

```
<definitions
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://sample"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
targetNamespace="http://sample" name="HelloService">
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://sample"
            schemaLocation="http://localhost:7022/hello/jaxws/HelloService?xsd=1" />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="hello">
    <part name="helloReq" type="tns:hello" />
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
    <part name="helloRes" type="tns:helloResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="HelloServicePort">
    <operation name="hello">
        <input wsam:Action="http://sample/HelloServicePort/helloRequest"
            message="tns:hello" />
        <output wsam:Action="http://sample/HelloServicePort/helloResponse"
            message="tns:helloResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="HelloServicePortBinding" type="tns:HelloServicePort">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
        style="rpc" />
    <operation name="hello">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="" />
        <input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="http://sample" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" namespace="http://sample" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="HelloService">
    <port name="HelloServicePort" binding="tns:HelloServicePortBinding">
        <soap12:address location="http://localhost:7022/hello/jaxws/HelloService" />
    </port>
</service>
```

Is this the default behavior or a bug in JAX-WS? Is there any workaround to make this work without changing the wsdl?
Please share some pointers.

Thanks.